# Show virtual keyboard on Android device

Tags: android, vb.net

Iam writing VB .NET application, which will run on Windows CE machine and Android device too. On Windows device it works good, immediately i can see virtual keyboard on screen, but when i want to see  virtual keyboard on Android device i have to tap to textbox.

```
How can i display virtual keyboard  immediately on android device?
```

Comment: No, Iam writing  vb .net app  no android app

Comment: Owh, I'm sorry, handled to fast.